# How to use a Multi FQL query from php with Hashtag

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, fql.multiquery

I am trying to use the results from the first query in the second query using the #query1 syntax.

E.g.

```
fql?q={"query1":"SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()","my name":"SELECT name FROM profile WHERE id IN (SELECT uid2 FROM #query1)"}
```

I can see that this works fine in the fql query simulator at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer.

But when i try to send this query via a PHP, i am unable to run it.
Code:

```
$fql_multiquery_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'
    . 'fql?q={"query1":"SELECT+uid2+FROM+friend+WHERE+uid1=me()","my+name":"SELECT+name+FROM+profile+WHERE+id+IN+(SELECT+uid2+FROM+#query1)"'
    . '&access_token=' . $access_token;
  $fql_multiquery_result = file_get_contents($fql_multiquery_url);
  $fql_multiquery_obj = json_decode($fql_multiquery_result, true);
```

I think the + before the # has some problems.

Comment: So you URL-encoded _some_ special characters like space, but you left the `#` as it is - why?

Comment: Replacing the space by + is shown in the FB Doc. How am I supposed to encode the # ?

Answer (score 0):

First, the obligatory scold: You shouldn't be using `file_get_contents()` to query the Facebook API. Use the SDK or cURL.

With PHP, the trick is you shouldn't be encoding anything manually. Write readable text and use the PHP internal functions to encode things for you.

```
$queries = array(
      'query1' => 'SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()',
      'myname' => 'SELECT name FROM profile WHERE id IN (SELECT uid2 FROM #query1)'
      //^ spaces aren't allowed in FQL query names.
    );
$params = array(
       'q' => json_encode($queries),
       'access_token' => $access_token
);
$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/fql?' . http_build_query($params);
```